# How do I determine whether a set spans or does not span a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$\{1+x^2,1+x+2x^2,x+x^2\}$ in $P_2$

Does the set span $P_2$?

I understand that the set is linearly dependent but how can I prove that the two independent elements cannot form every element in $P_2$? Does the set have to be linearly independent for it to span a particular vector space?

Answer (score 1):

A set can span a vector space without being linearly independent. However, if you know about dimensions then a set spanning the three-dimensional space $P_2$ must contain three linearly independent elements (and possibly additional elements).

Here, to show that the set is not spanning, you could also exhibit a single element of $P_2$ that is not writeable as linear combination of the given vectors. For example, can you see why $1$ is not in the span?

Comment: So I can just say that because P2 is a 3 dimensional vector space and the basis of the set contains only two vectors meaning the dimension of the basis = 2, the set cannot span P2?

Answer (score 1):

We Have a result, That

> "If a set is Linearly independent and has dimension same as that of Vector Space $V$, Then The set is a Basis for $V$."

So I assume that your vectors are not Linearly Independent.

$1+x^2 \quad \qquad= 1(1)+0(x)+1(x^2)$

$1+x+2x^2 \quad= 1(1)+1(x)+2(x^2)$

$x+x^2 \quad \qquad= 0(1)+1(x)+1(x^2)$.

So the matrix of the coefficients

> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 1 & 2 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}

Row reduce it to echelon form, You will get 2 non zer0 rows only, hence they are not linearly independent vectors. they dont span the vector Space.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be linearly independent for a set to span a vector space. What you'll want to do is check if you can get any element from $P_2$ from a linear of combination of the elements in your set. In this case, $\{1+x^2,1+x+2x^2,x+x^2\}$.